# Spring Boot - My unit tests are being skipped

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am migrating an existing project to boot. I created a brand new project using start.spring.io and copied over the source code, etc. Everything compiles, but when I do a 'mvn test' it compiles the classes but then only executes the default 'ApplicationTests' (created by start.spring.io).

Here's an excerpt from the maven output:

```
    [INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ pendview ---
    [INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
    [INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\dev\pendview2\src\test\resources
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ pendview ---
    [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
    [INFO] Compiling 26 source files to C:\dev\pendview2\target\test-classes
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.15:test (default-test) @ pendview ---
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

What's even stranger is that if I pass '-Dtest=TestAuthController' then it does run that specific unit test:

```
    [INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ pendview ---
    [INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
    [INFO] Compiling 26 source files to C:\dev\pendview2\target\test-classes
    [INFO]
    [INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.15:test (default-test) @ pendview ---
    [INFO] Surefire report directory: C:\dev\pendview2\target\surefire-reports

    (skipped output of AuthControllerTest for brevity)

    -------------------------------------------------------
     T E S T S
    -------------------------------------------------------Results :

    Tests run: 6, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

What am I doing wrong? Does spring boot setup a surefire config that I'm not conforming to?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!
-Trey

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Spring Boot configures the Surefire plugin to run all test classes that have a name ending with `Test` or `Tests` but not starting with `Abstract`. You can see this [configuration in the `spring-boot-starter-parent` pom](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.1.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-parent/pom.xml#L86-L92). If your test class is named `TestAuthController` then it doesn't match this configuration. Renaming it to `AuthControllerTest` or `AuthControllerTests` should fix your problem.

Comment: I also think that JUnit 4 tests are ignored since spring boot 2.4

Comment: As of 2.4, JUnit's vintage engine is no longer included by default. This means that JUnit-4 based tests won't run (and probably won't compile either). If you're not in a position to migrate to JUnit 5, you can reinstate the vintage engine as [described in Spring Boot's release notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.4-Release-Notes#junit-5s-vintage-engine-removed-from-spring-boot-starter-test).

Answer (score 1):

Seems for me there is some issue with Maven `surefire` plugin, when it doesn't detect tests, if your test class name doesn't end with `Tests` suffix. :-)

Answer (score 1):

Try this command in your console/terminal:

```
mvn clean install
```

But first navigate to directory of your tests.
If you wish to skip tests use this command:

```
mvn clean install -Dmaven.test.skip
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems Andy's answer should be updated for Spring Boot 2.X. I can't see surefire config anywhere now. Probably there were too many complains about this convention.