# mvn test not running test class

Tags: maven-3, maven-surefire-plugin

I am trying to run a maven phase: 
mvn test

However, the tests are not being executed:

1. The test class is located in: src/test/java/TestRESTTransactionResourceController
2. When I rename the class to have the postfix Test the mvn test command does pick up the test:
   src/test/java/RESTTransactionResourceControllerTest

I ran mvn -X test in order to get more output and it looks like the following pattern is searched for:

```
  <includes>
    <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
  </includes>
```

I thought the default for this plugin was:

```
  <includes>
    <include>**/Test*.java</include>
    <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
  </includes>
```

Anyway, part of my pom.xml is as follows:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.1</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.18.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        <goal>verify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-javadoc-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.3</version>
            <configuration>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Any ideas please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Surefire Plugin will automatically include all test classes with the following wildcard patterns:

```
"**/Test*.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that start with "Test".
"**/*Test.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Test".
"**/*Tests.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "Tests".
"**/*TestCase.java" - includes all of its subdirectories and all Java filenames that end with "TestCase".
```

to include/exclude test cases, please see

[https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/inclusion-exclusion.html][1]

Comment: Thanks, thats what I do not understand though, it is skipping **/Test*.java. Below is the output from the logs after running mvn -X test:
  </failIfNoSpecifiedTests>
  <failIfNoTests>${failIfNoTests}</failIfNoTests>
  <forkCount default-value="1">${forkCount}</forkCount>
  <forkMode default-value="once">${forkMode}</forkMode>
  <forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds>${surefire.timeout}</forkedProcessTimeoutInSeconds>
  <groups>${groups}</groups>
  <includes>
    <include>**/*Tests.java</include>
    <include>**/*Test.java</include>
  </includes>

Answer (score 0):

It is because I am using the following spring boot plugin inside my module:

```
<plugin>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

This changes the search criteria to look for test classes ending with Test or Tests. 
The following link helped: 
[Spring Boot - My unit tests are being skipped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25813941/spring-boot-my-unit) tests-are-being-skipped

I changed the surefire plugin in my module to override this configuration.